# Free C# compiler in Unix

Tags: c#, unix

I am in need of a free compiler for C# language in Unix. Would someone please point me to the packages or better, use of terminal commands in Mint to install the software [sorry i am low with Unix system]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try out http://mono-project.com

Just type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

Also you may need MonoDevelop - free IDE for .NET languages

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Answer (score 5):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) ships with several [C# compilers](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler).